# ...при том() что() когда работаю

Tags: пунктуация, спп

"Зарплата неплохая, получаю около 30-35 тысяч, при том() что() когда работаю, деньги почти не трачу".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ кажется очевидным: "Зарплата неплохая, получаю около 30-35 тысяч, при том что, когда работаю, деньги почти не трачу". ПРИ ТОМ(,) ЧТО - союз, при том что
отделять "что" запятой нет причин :) (см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3). "Когда работаю" - придаточное предложение времени, выделяется запятыми.

Comment: Вопрос не касался правильности раздельного написания "при()том", поэтому в ответе я тоже не касался этой темы.

Answer (score 1):

**Пример из Нацкорпуса:**

Что меня поражало в нем, так это потрясающая память, **притом, что когда мы с ним познакомились,** ему было уже под семьдесят. [Читая Бориса Акунина (2003) // «Вестник США», 2003.07.23]

Запятая  после ПРИТОМ кажется лишней, а вот отсутствие запятой перед КОГДА кажется обоснованным.

Остановимся на следующем варианте: **Зарплата неплохая, получаю около 30-35 тысяч, притом что когда работаю, денег почти не трачу.**

Вообще говоря, грамматика здесь не такая простая и очевидная. **ПРИТОМ** ― это  сочинительный присоединительный союз, а **ПРИТОМ ЧТО** ― какой? Скорее всего, подчинительный с присоединительно-сопоставительным значением. Сравниваем две ситуации, и как-то не хочется расчленять сложноподчиненное предложение "когда работаю, денег почти не трачу" и выделять вставочную часть "когда работаю".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Правило о двойном союзе КОГДА... ТО, ЕСЛИ...ТО общеизвестно, но оно слишком формально, чтобы применяться всегда, везде и всюду. Всё-таки основная задача пунктуации ― это помощь в правильном прочтении смысла предложения, а двойные союзы - **это не единственная тема, которая регулирует постановку запятой в данном случае.**

Answer (score 1):

***Зарплата неплохая, получаю около 30-35 тысяч, при том что, когда работаю, деньги почти не трачу.***

Стык союзов ПРИ ТОМ ЧТО и КОГДА. Так как у союза КОГДА нет второй части, запятая на стыке (перед когда) ставится.

Исправила.

Comment: Екатерина, Вы написали "Стык союзов ПРИТОМ ЧТО и КОГДА. Так как у союза ПРИТОМ ЧТО нет второй части ТО, запятая на стыке ставится." Но запятую перед КОГДА поставили. Или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: "При том что" или "притом что"?

Comment: @Матвей Дёмин, я видел огромную дискуссию на эту тему. Ответы Грамоты.ру противоречивы.

Comment: Запятая ставится, так как у союза КOГДА нет второй части ТОГДА. Запятая не ставится, если есть ТОГДА: Егор привел неожиданное для Левина замечание, что когда он жил у хороших господ, тогда он был своими господами доволен (по Л. Толстому).

Answer (score 0):

Зарплата неплохая, получаю около 30-35 тысяч, притом, когда работаю, деньги почти не трачу.

"Что"- лишнее. "Притом" - присоединительный союз, между "притом" и "когда" нужна запятая, так как можно сделать перестановку:

Зарплата неплохая, получаю около 30-35 тысяч, притом деньги почти не трачу, когда работаю.